# I need to extract id's values with casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```html
<div id=111 class="image">
<div id=222 class="image">
<div id=333 class="image">
<div id=444 class="image">
<div id=555 class="image">
```

```js
 id = casper.evaluate(function() { 
                return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("image"), function(e) {
                return e.getElementById;
                });
                });
this.echo(anun);
```

I would just like to extract the values of the id's, the class name is always the same

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID-Values via

```
var listIDs = casper.getElementsAttribute('div.image', 'id');
```